# bind controls to class properties from different thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, binding

My class is in different thread from the ui controls thread.
how can i make a binding between class properties to the ui controls ?

without binding i use Dispatch...

Tanx

Comment: sorry, but I think is not completely clear. Is your class a view model or anything else?

Comment: no, it's not t view model. i have some object which creates in thread A, and i want to bind some controls (from the main application thread) to the properties of this object...